# Trying to acquireTokenSilentAsync from android app

Tags: java, android, azure-ad-msal

I'm currently using

> implementation 'com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:1.4.0'

to connect to the app via azure , my acquireToken() works fine and I get the user in response ( I save it in the SharedPrefs)

After that (next login) I'm trying to do acquireTokenSilentAsync like so :

```
      SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences();

      Gson gson = new Gson();
      String json = pref.getString("IAccount", "");


      if(!json.isEmpty()){
          Account account = gson.fromJson(json, Account.class);
          AcquireTokenSilentParameters parameters = new AcquireTokenSilentParameters.Builder()
              .withScopes(Arrays.asList(scopes))
              .forAccount(account)
              .fromAuthority(getAuthority())
              .withCallback(getSilentAuthInteractiveCallback())
              .build();
          application.acquireTokenSilentAsync(parameters);
      }
```

And get to the onError callback with the exception of :

```
>  E/onError: exception : com.microsoft.identity.client.Account cannot be cast to com.microsoft.identity.client.MultiTenantAccount
```

Any ideas what's missing ?

Much Appreciated.

Comment: #1 Synchronous token acquisition works, but asynchronous acquisition doesn't? #2 If it is true, show both to compare them!

Comment: app.acquireToken(activity, scopes, getAuthInteractiveCallback());
this works , but this -> acquireTokenSilentAsync doesn't acquireTokenSilent also not working

Comment: Can you show getSilentAuthInteractiveCallback() method code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page may help:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/accounts-overview

In particular, they don't use a Gson and they cast the account to prevent the exception you get in their example code.

I would start by trying to cast like this:

```
IMultiTenantAccount multiTenantAccount = (IMultiTenantAccount)account;
```

and using that as the argument in forAccount().

Comment: saving the account with gson was the problem , GG